# WPF MVVM DataRow Binding

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datatable, binding

I have a Textbox bound to a column in a DataRow.  How can I get the setter of the DataRow to fire in code-behind when the Textbox Text is changed by the user?

XAML:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding NewDataRow[ColumnName1], ValidatesOnExceptions=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"></TextBox>
```

Code-behind:

```
DataRow newImpellerClipRow;
    public DataRow NewImpellerClipRow {
        get { return newImpellerClipRow; }
        set
        {
            newImpellerClipRow = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged();
            SubmitCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: You are probably better off using data templates

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into it.  Do you have any insight on how to trigger the setter for a textbox bound to a column of a DataRow?

Comment: It is the setter of data-bound property that is fired when the text in the TextBox is changed.

Comment: In this case, the data binding is to a DataColumn in the DataRow. How do I catch the DataColumn setter without explicitly defining the DataColumn as a Property?